# How can i use a user defined function to call other functions?

Tags: python, pandas, function, oop, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a user defined function to call in other functions. So i have table and when I am analysing each variable, I have to type in `.hist()` `.size()` `.describe()` etc for each one. I want to streamline this by create a function I can call to do this for me.

This is what i have:

```
class no_show_data:
    def __init__(self, df, col_name):
        self.df = df
        self.col_name = col_name
    
    def hist(self):
        return self.df.hist(no_show_data = col_name);
    
    def describe(self):
        return self.df[col_name].describe();
    
    def size(self):
        return self.df[col_name].size();
    
    def information(self):
        print(self.hist(), self.describe(), self.size());
```

and I'm trying to call it like this:

```
c = no_show_data(df, "age");
c.information();
```

I get an error stating: `AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'no_show_data'`.
However, I get nothing else from the `.size()` etc

Comment: what is this 'Rectangle' thing? also your `col_name` on `hist`, `describe` and `size` should be `self.col_name`

Comment: also include the full traceback of the error, but regardless it look like the error come from your `hist` method on `self.df.hist(no_show_data = col_name)`, "no_show_data" is not a valid keyword for df.hist

Comment: oh, and in python you don't need to end your lines with `;`

Comment: @Copperfield its the error that popped up when trying to make the histogram i guess. thank you, I'll try that

Comment: @Copperfield Thank you! you got me on the right track!